# Submitting a form when using an onSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form onSubmit is calling:

```
onsubmit="validate(this); return false;"
```

validate() is as follows:

```
function validate(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "ajax/validate_check.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : $("#" + obj.id).serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            $('#' + obj.id + ' :input.form_errors').removeClass('form_errors')
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(data['error_count'] >= 1) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    $('#' + i).addClass('form_errors');
                });
            } else {
                $('#' + obj.id).submit();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I have 0 errors it's trying to submit the form but I'm getting an infinite loop. I realize it's happening because my onSubmit calls the function again. How do I actually submit the form when I'm ready? What is the proper way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Your validate function should return either true or false depending on errors.

```
  onsubmit = "return validate(this)"

  function validate(obj){
     ...
     if(data['error_count'] >= 1) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $('#' + i).addClass('form_errors');
            });
            return false; //stop submitting
        } else {
            return true;//continue submitting
        }
  }
```

Although, since you are using jquery:

```
     $("#formid").submit(function(){
           //your validation code
     });
```

may be better.

Check out [this page](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for more details. There is a good example.

Comment: The OP uses AJAX to validate the form, so this doesn't help.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. Any idea why?

Comment: In that case move the validation to the button click and on validation success then submit form.

Comment: I was thinking about that but I want the user to be able to hit enter to submit the form.

Comment: the return is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are already submitting the form for validation.

On `} else {` you can't submit it again, as you noticed. You should call a function to submit it to `whatever_process_the_validated_data.php`

Though I'd suggest having the same `.php` to validate and process data - a class or function to each. That way you can:

```
$('.forms_that_need_validation').submit(function() {
$.ajax({
    url : "ajax/data_validation_and_processing.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : $(this).serialize(),
    success : function(data) {
        $(this + ' :input.form_errors').removeClass('form_errors')
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        if(data['error_count'] >= 1) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $('#' + i).addClass('form_errors');
            });
        } else {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
return false;
});
```

What happens is, if the data fails to be validated, it returns an error - you should code you `.php` in order not to process the data if it's not validated. Otherwise, the data was validated and processed already, then it just reloads the page.